# Way to display list of users in a horizontal container, rather than vertically and uncontained?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using this WordPress code http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-randomly-display-registered-users-in-wordpress/

```
function wpb_random_users() { 

global $wpdb;

$randomusers = '<ul class="random-users">';

// Query database for users
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename, user_url, user_email FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

// Display users in a list
foreach ($usernames as $username) {

if (!$username->user_url) :

$randomusers .= '<li>' .get_avatar($username->user_email, 45) .$username->user_nicename."</li>";

else :

$randomusers .= '<li>' .get_avatar($username->user_email, 45).'<a href="'.$username->user_url.'">'.$username->user_nicename."</a></li>";

endif;
}
$randomusers .= '</ul>';

return $randomusers;  
}

add_shortcode('randomusers','wpb_random_users');
```

which works to list users vertically. But I'm wondering how to make the users list horizontally instead, preferably contained in a moving carousel.

How might I change the code to at least partially achieve this, like placing the users horizontally in a box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the css file

```
ul.random-users li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sadly, adding that to the style.css file doesn't have a visual effect. Also, for testing purposes I typed `padding:50px; margin-bottom:50px; background:red;` under `display: inline;` and it still had no effect. I also tried changing `ul.random-users li` to `li` and emptied the cache and no effect still. Eep. Not sure why it doesn't seem to work. But it seems like it should!

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind! I just needed to edit the CSS in the right place within WordPress. The code works great. Thank you!!